Laravel backpack custom buttom with blade file doesnt recognize the operation
setup from the crud controller made by backpack
public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\WebServices\CartBackend\QuotesDetails::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/cart');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('Quotes', 'Carrito: Quotes Details');

        $opertion = $this->crud->getOperation();
        Log::info('Current Operation: ' . $opertion);


        if (
            !\Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo($opertion) or
            !\Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('cart')

        ) {
            \Alert::error('Unauthorized access - you do not have the necessary permissions to see this page.')->flash();
            $this->crud->denyAccess([$opertion]);
        }
    }

this function should work as a data edit
public function editLinkify($id)
    {
        $this->crud->setOperation('editLinkify');

        $opertion = $this->crud->getOperation();

        Log::info('Current Operation ed: ' . $opertion);

        $quoteDetail = QuotesDetails::findOrFail($id);
        $quote = DB::connection('cart')->table('quote')->where('id', $quoteDetail->id)->first();
        // Verifica si se encontró un registro en la tabla quote
        $b_account_rut = $quote ? $quote->b_account_rut : null;

        return view('ModuleQuoteDetails.Summary.edit', compact('quoteDetail', 'b_account_rut'));
    }

route
 Route::get('cart/{id}/edit-linkify', 'WebServices\CartBackend\QuotesDetails\QuotesDetailsCrudController@editLinkify')
        ->name('cart.edit-linkify');

button
@if ($crud->hasAccess('update', $entry))
        <a href="{{ url($crud->route . '/' . $entry->getKey() . '/edit-linkify') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-link">
            <i class="la la-edit"></i> Edit linkify
        </a>
@endif


What I am getting in both the setup and function logs is empty when I click my button.
It is not the case if I go to edit which is part of backpack, there I do get an update log
something in setup() is messing with my new buttom i think this one doesnt get the new edit-linkify operation:
$opertion = $this->crud->getOperation();
this one in the edit method pass the editlinkify but, this triggers after clicking the buttom :
$this->crud->setOperation('editLinkify');
docs:
https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-buttons#adding-a-custom-button-with-a-blade-file-1
I want to ensure that my button delivers the update or edit-linkify operation, rather, that it does not arrive empty, since my setup() if condition throws an error when an empty operation arrives
